# Собрать проект с CMake в MacOS

Tags: macos, git, cmake, qt, c++

Загрузил проект с https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx.git. При сборке Qt 5.2 показывает ошибку:

> CMake Error at /Applications/CMake
> 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1386
> (message):   Found unsuitable Qt
> version "5.2.0" from
> /Users/DerKode/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/bin/qmake,
> this code requires Qt 4.x Call Stack
> (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:166 (find_package)

В системе MacOS 10.9 установлен CMake 2.8.12.1

Comment: как по мне,так явно пишется, что у Вас Qt 5.2, а программу нужно компилировать с помощью 4.х. Установите правильную версию sdk (например, 4.8.5) или изучайте Qt и перепишите, чтобы оно и на 5 нормально компилировалось.

Comment: Переписать нужно файл CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: скорее всего одним ним дело не закончиться. Похоже, что этой программе нужен именно 4.6.0. Можно конечно исправить, но будьте готовы исправлять ещё в десятках мест.

Comment: точно не закончится, как минимум все qt 4.x приложения стартовали с QApplication, а в 5.x его вынесли в отдельный модуль widgets (вместе со всеми потомками QWidget) и заменили на QCoreApplication, который вроде полегче и точно не завязан на гуй (запускал приложение с ним на сервере без иксов)

Comment: @aknew, мне надо что-то поменять в CMakeLists.txt QApplication на QCoreApplication? Или как?

Comment: Думаю для начала, нужно почитать книгу. А простой подменой так просто большой проект не возьмешь.

Я не уверен, что я сам бы его правильно портировал на 5.2 за приемлемое время.

Comment: @derkode, это не в CmakeLists, это в самом исходном коде + если там виджеты есть то оно не прокатет, это только одна проблема, которая встречается при переходе с 4.х на 5.х даже в хеловордах. А в целом согласен с KoVadim, портирование с одной версии на другую не такая тривиальная вещь как кажется, тем более что где-то около 4.7 начали делить еще и сам qt на модули т.е. там даже при переносе на 4.7-4.8 есть шанс огрести проблем, а уж про 5.2, которая вышла меньше недли назад, и говорить страшно